# Table with multiple cells isn't resized to the window

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I have a table and it doesn't resize to the window size. I have `overflow` set to `hidden` and I want it to stay that way. I want to be able to scroll inside of the table.

Here is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4mgocaLu/1/

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
it set a width that had a maximum width 800px as an example you can change it if you want it will minimize not lower than 200px.

```
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:800px;
    min-width:200px;
}
```

I hope this is what you meant was

Comment: Doesn't work, when I try it, it stays the same except the width is a little different.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding

```
overflow-y: scroll;
min-height: .01%;
height: 350px;
max-width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
```

to the div

Answer (score -1):

Add below code of css

```
.tableResponsive {
    overflow-x: auto;
    min-height: .01%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding:10px;
}
```

**[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/v8o3j7wf/16)**

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 padding-right: 2px;
 padding-left: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.tableResponsive {
    overflow-x: auto;
    min-height: .01%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding:10px;
}

table {
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
}

th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableResponsive">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>Test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried it in my app, tried it in the fiddle, both didn't work for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, but that might be a platform thing.

Comment: but i posted working snippet is not working as well for you ?

Comment: I tried it on firefox, chrome, and my electron app (chrome) and nothing works

Comment: @Shakti Phartiyal please read comments the OP's use another platform (" Doesn't work for me, but that might be a platform thing") and if you actually used it you didn't comment ( 
"This does not work")